# Issues getting systemd service to start (Jessie)

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I've got a systemd service which I need to have run prior to networking having started and I'm struggling with it a little. According to this: 
[Running Services After the Network is up](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) I need to use **Before=network-pre.target**, however my service isn't starting.

Dependencies:

```
root@server:~# systemctl list-dependencies my-script --reverse
my-script.service
● └─network-pre.target (has a red dot next to it)
```

The actual unit itself:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/my-script
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: One thing which does strike me is that Jessie appears to be using an init script to control networking - obviously Systemd can deal with this but I wonder if it doesn't give you the same flexibility with hooks that a fully systemd-ised networking service does?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Wants= line as you are listing something impossible to satisfy: start the service before network-pre.target but also after (Wants) it. So the unit should read as:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script
Before=network-pre.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/my-script
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/ says "Services that want to be run before the network is configured should place Before=network-pre.target and also set Wants=network-pre.target to pull it in." If we don't put Wants=, it locks up (and then only starts much later) because nothing pulls network-pre.target.

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=@CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY@

Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/sbin/my-script.sh

RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```